# GTKMM buttons in a grid

Tags: c++, gtkmm

just learned the concept of GTKMM and found out that I enjoyed this, compared to just C++, which is pretty boring just programming in the terminal. As I decided to create a code that will make a 8 x 8 buttons of table, I encountered a problem, which is how to set every button to my desired position, because the code I created just makes 64 buttons horizontally. Can anyone help me here? Thanks

examplewindow.h (The code the class attributes and methods)

```
#ifndef GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H
#define GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H

#include <gtkmm.h>

class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
  ExampleWindow();
  virtual ~ExampleWindow();

private:
  // Signal handlers:
  void on_button_numbered(const Glib::ustring& data);

  // Child widgets:
  Gtk::Grid m_grid;
  Gtk::Button button[8][8];
};

#endif /* GTKMM_EXAMPLEWINDOW_H */
```

examplewindow.cc (The code for modifying the attributes and methods)

```
#include <iostream>
#include "examplewindow.h"

ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()
{
  set_title("Mr. Sandman");
  set_border_width(12);
  int i, j;
  add(m_grid);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      {
          m_grid.add(button[i][j]);
      }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
      {
          button[i][j].signal_clicked().connect(
    sigc::bind<Glib::ustring>( sigc::mem_fun(*this,
      &ExampleWindow::on_button_numbered), "button 1") );
      }
  }
  m_grid.show_all();
}

ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow()
{
}


void
ExampleWindow::on_button_numbered(const Glib::ustring& data)
{
  std::cout << data << " was pressed" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cc (The main function)

```
#include "examplewindow.h"
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

  ExampleWindow window;

  // Shows the window and returns when it is closed.
  return app->run(window);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `m_Grid.add()` try using `attach()` or `attach_next_to()`

so you can either give row/column position in your loop or attach button 9 below button 1 and button 2 to the right of button 1

https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Grid.html#a9c425e95660daff60a77fc0cafc18115